# Ubuntu 12.04 add existing user to group

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have problem with Ubuntu.

I'm trying add user tbalicek to group www-data but the following commands doesn't work.

```
tbalicek@UBK-LINUX:/var/www$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data tbalicek
tbalicek@UBK-LINUX:/var/www$ groups
tbalicek sudo
tbalicek@UBK-LINUX:/var/www$ groups tbalicek
tbalicek : tbalicek www-data
```

I don't understand why groups and groups tbalicek return different results?? When I'm loged like tbalicek

When I'm trying mkdir like tbalicek in folder where si own group www-data I get: permission denied

```
tbalicek@UBK-LINUX:/var/www$ ls -ltr
total 20
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   31 Mar 27 13:52 index.php
drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 27 17:16 pelnar
drwxrwxr-x 16 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 27 17:21 redmine
drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  3 17:54 taskagent
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     root       22 Apr 10 14:35 info.php
tbalicek@UBK-LINUX:/var/www$
```

Comment: Please edit your post and paste the output of ls -ltr for the /var/www directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group assignments don't take effect in the current shell. You have to log out and log back in to see the group changes.

From the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo) for `sudo`:

> After being added to a new group the user must log out and then log back in again for the new group to take effect. Groups are only assigned to users at login time. A most common source of confusion is that people add themselves to a new group but then do not log out and back in again and then have problems because the group is not assigned.

You might get a better response for this sort of question on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

Try the newgrp command:

```
ts@cmp:~$ id
uid=1001(ts) gid=1001(ts) groups=1001(ts),27(sudo)
ts@cmp:~$ newgrp www-data
ts@cmp:~$ id
uid=1001(ts) gid=33(www-data) groups=1001(ts),27(sudo),33(www-data)
```

Just a nitpick, 'sudo adduser user group' will also add a user to a group and I find the syntax easier to remember than using usermod.